# Is it possible to configure protocol buffers / protostuff to not generate the default empty constructor for a message?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, default-constructor, protostuff

I noticed that protocol buffers / protostuff generate the Java default no-argument constructor when there are required fields. Is there a way to instrument it to not do it for a specific message?

## Example

```
message Response {
  required ErrorCode errorCode;
  repeated Data;
}
```

I would like it to generate only one constructor

```
public Response(ErrorCode errorCode) {};
```

Comment: How are you generating this protocol buffer? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated doesn't say anything about constructors.

Comment: I learned now that we use protostuff.

Comment: Is it a bean, or generated using code that generates beans?  Because if so beans always require a zero argument constructor.  So if that is the case, you might not be able to do that.

Comment: Not a bean, good point.